# Retrieve "July 10" and "Last Tues" from SQLite Date field in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have this date in my **history** table with field `dtEnd="2012-07-10 11:07:00"`
and i want to retrieve **July 10** and **Last Tues** both from this date separately.

Can anybody suggest a query for doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While surfing, I came to know that it is not possible to get Month and date name instead you have to use your logic for that.

I got the solution, I am getting month and date with:

```
Select strftime('%m-%d','dtend')'Date' from history
```

And then I am extracting month and day number separately and then passing that month number to my own function with switch case to give month name.

That's it and I got my solution.